# Delete dataframe timestamps which are in second dataframe intervals

Tags: python, pandas, merge, timestamp, intervals

Given: two dataframes with columns= (id, timestamp), another dataframe columns =(id,start_interval, end_interval), id's always the same. One of them consist timestemp sec by sec another one have only timestamp intervals.

df_timestamp

```
    id      timestamp
1   11006   1365       
2   11006   1366       
3   11006   1367
4   11006   1368
5   11006   1369   
...
101 11006   1465
102 11006   1466
103 11006   1467
104 11006   1468
...
```

df_intervals

```
    id      start_interval    end_interval
1   11006   1250              1366
2   11006   1369              1455
...
12  11006   1466              1467
13  11006   1620              1950
...
```

Task: I need to make new dataframe where **df_timestamp** ['timestamp'] values are not in or between **df_intervals** 'intervals' values.

Output:

new_df

```
   id     timestamp  
1  11006  1367       
2  11006  1368 
...
77 11006  1465
78 11006  1468
...
```

I try to `merge()` they, but this dfs are pretty Large. Also try to add some logic expression and have failed. Case with merge seems to have worked but take infinity time to running. Furthermore, after merge the suitable `.loc` is required.

Is there are any more elegant and effective way to make this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need it:

```
crit=  df_timestamp.timestamp.isin(df_intervals.start_interval) \
     | df_timestamp.timestamp.isin(df_intervals.end_interval)

df_timestamp.loc[~crit]
```

**EDIT:**

```
#For readablity:
    df_interval, df_timestamp= dfi,dft


    matched= dft.groupby( lambda idx: \
                           (  dfi.start_interval.le(dft.loc[idx,"timestamp"]) \
                            & dfi.end_interval.ge(dft.loc[idx,"timestamp"])).any() ) \
                    .groups[False]                                                                               

    Out:
       df_timestamp.loc[matched]  

index     id  timestamp
2          3  11006     1367.0
3          4  11006     1368.0
5  101 11006   1465        NaN
6  102 11006   1466        NaN
7  103 11006   1467        NaN
8  104 11006   1468        NaN
```

**EDIT2:**
A variant of the prevoius code, with list comprehension:

```
dft.loc[ [(dfi.start_interval.gt(ts) | dfi.end_interval.lt(ts)).all() for ts in dft.timestamp] ]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it also mustn't be between intervals

Comment: See the edited code above. I wonder if this solution is faster or more "elegant" than your one.